# Flutter SQLite Syntax Error near TEXT decimal point

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sqlite

I can't seem to figure out what this syntax error is, I have tried TEXT & BLOB for both the mac & the image fields but nothing seems to work. Please help!

```
customQuery("CREATE TABLE Profile ("
    "mac TEXT,"
    "image TEXT,"
    "name TEXT,"
    "age INT,"
    "nationality TEXT,"
    "profession TEXT,"
    "about TEXT"
    ")");

onPressed: () {
        profile.add(Profile(
            mac: _platformVersion,
            image: imagePath,
            name: nameController.text,
            age: ageController.text,
            nationality: nationalityController.text,
            profession: professionController.text,
            about: aboutController.text));

        DBProvider.db.customQuery("INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about)"
            " VALUES (${profile[0].mac},${profile[0].image},"
            "${profile[0].name},${profile[0].age},${profile[0].nationality},"
            "${profile[0].profession},${profile[0].about});");
           },
```

& this is the error

```
    E/SQLiteLog( 4520): (1) near ".0": syntax error in "INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES (0.0.0.0.0.0,/data/user/0/com.test.fltestar/cache/scaled_image_picker3315305739073272987.jpg,test,35,test
E/flutter ( 4520): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near ".0": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES (0.0.0.0.0.0,/data/user/0/com.test.test/cache/scaled_image_picker3315305739073272987.jpg,test,35,test,test,test);) sql 'INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES (0.0.0.0.0.0,/data/user/0/com.test.test/cache/scaled_image_picker3315305739073272987.jpg,test,35,test,test,test);' args []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INSERT syntax is, in fact, wrong.
Here's your actual syntax:

```
INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES (0.0.0.0.0.0,/data/user/0/com.test.fltestar/cache/scaled_image_picker3315305739073272987.jpg,test,35,test,test,test);
```

But the values are not expressed as TEXTs for all TEXT fields. It should be something like this:

```
INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES ('0.0.0.0.0.0','/data/user/0/com.test.fltestar/cache/scaled_image_picker3315305739073272987.jpg','test',35,'test','test','test');
```

Also, I would suggest you use libraries like moor, that helps you a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gregorio ! That was a  silly mistake. But now I get this error: 
E/SQLiteLog( 4520): (20) statement aborts at 5:
E/SQLiteQuery( 4520): exception: datatype mismatch (code 20 SQLITE_MISMATCH); query: INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES ('0.0.0.0.0.0','/data/user/0/com.test.test/cache/scaled_image_picker3315305739073272987.jpg','test','35','test','test','test');

Comment: The 35 value should be an integer, but you are referring to it as a string in this version of the query. Just switch it back to being an integer.

Comment: Silly mistake again, however, I still do get a datatype mismatch after changing the data type to TEXT for the age column & vice versa.
Anything else that you can see?
Just fyi (the platformversion & image are strings)